# Помощь с выбором движка

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, движок

Подскажите, какой можно выбрать движок для создания игр (не UE, Unity), если ты только планируешь погрузиться в эту тематику? Зависит ли качество текстур от движка? Например, если я захочу написать игру аля-гта5 и выберу sfml, получится ли реализовать схожую графику? Или вообще сразу взяться за DirectX?

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хорошо, есть ли смысл  учить DX для создания игры, а не движка? Если да, то какого автора посоветуете?

Comment: Если только планируешь погружаться, то стоит начать с чего-нибудь посильного, возможно текстово-консольного, а никак не гта. DirectX и прочие графические API требуют уверенного владения языком программирования и познаний в геометрии и линейной алгебре.

Comment: @user7860670 текстово-консольного я уже реализовал, я имел ввиду в плане графики